# Interactive plotly boxplot with ipywidgets

Tags: python, plotly, visualization, ipywidgets

I am trying to create an interactive boxplot with ipywidgets and Plotly.

I started by looking at [this example](https://plotly.com/python/v3/figurewidget-app/)

While this is fine, I'd like to change the groupings of the boxplot based on a dropdown input.

With `interact` I can do this:

```
import datetime
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import plotly.graph_objects as go
from ipywidgets import widgets

df = pd.read_csv(
 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yankev/testing/master/datasets/nycflights.csv')
df = df.drop(df.columns[[0]], axis=1)

from ipywidgets import interact

def view_image(col):
    fig = go.FigureWidget()
    for val in df[col].unique():
        groupData = df.query(f'{col} == "{val}"')
        fig.add_trace(
            go.Box(y = groupData['distance'],
                  name = val)
        )
    fig.show()
    

    
interact(view_image, col = ['origin', 'carrier'])
```

And the result is that I can change the column based on which the data is grouped.

However, I would like to have more control on the widgets, like in the official example.

This is what I am trying (and failing):

```
# Assign an empty figure widget with two traces
gdata = []
for origin in df.origin.unique():
    groupData = df.query(f'origin == "{origin}"')
    gdata.append(
        go.Box(y = groupData['distance'],
              name = origin)
    )
g = go.FigureWidget(data=gdata,
                    layout=go.Layout(
                        title=dict(
                            text='NYC FlightDatabase'
                        ),
                        barmode='overlay'
                    ))

def response_box(change):
    col = column.value
    with g.batch_update():
        gdata = []
        for val in df[col].unique():
            groupData = df.query(f'{col} == "{val}"')
            gdata.append(
                go.Box(y = groupData['distance'],
                      name = val)
            )
        g.data = gdata

column = widgets.Dropdown(
    options=['origin','carrier']
)
column.observe(response_box, 'value')
container2 = widgets.HBox([column])
widgets.VBox([container2,
              g])
```

Note that since I have new groupings, I cannot just go into `g.data[index].y` and change per index, but I have to re-generate the figure as in the `interact` function.

This particular iteration gives me a "you cannot update data directly" error. I tried in a few different ways, but I don't seem to find one that works.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- it's not clear how you want to interact with the dimensions of data.  So I've gone with defining **x** and **color** of figure, plus filtering by *origin, dest, carrier*
- box plots are far simpler to create using **Plotly Express** so have used that
- it then really simplifies to passing parameters. Have used https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Using%20Interact.html with decorator

```
import datetime
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
from ipywidgets import widgets
from ipywidgets import interact

df = pd.read_csv(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yankev/testing/master/datasets/nycflights.csv"
)
df = df.drop(df.columns[[0]], axis=1)

@interact
def view_image(
    col=widgets.Dropdown(
        description="Plot:", value="carrier", options=["origin", "carrier"]
    ),
    filtercol=widgets.Dropdown(
        description="Filter by:", value="carrier", options=["origin", "dest", "carrier"]
    ),

    filter=widgets.Text(
        description="Filter:", value=""
    ),
):
    # check if filter results in any rows... if not all data...
    if df[filtercol].eq(filter).any():
        dfp = df.loc[df[filtercol].eq(filter)]
    else:
        dfp = df
    fig = px.box(dfp, x=col, y="distance", color=col)
    go.FigureWidget(fig.to_dict()).show()
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah, Interact works pretty well, but it doesn't really give me control on the widgets layout. However, looking at the link to their documentation, I found `interactive_output` which should give me more control on how the widgets are arranged.